# How to export pyspark big data to xls or csv?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, bigdata, export-to-csv, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a xls or csv file from pyspark dataframe but my resulting data is very big and I got `{ "error_code": "BAD_REQUEST", "message": "content size (17544861) exceeded the limit 10485761" }`

I tried to drop some columns but that did not work either. how can I solve this?